# Django ORM - How to get max price and the associated date

Tags: python, django, orm

To follow the price of what I buy at the grocery.
I have these models :

```
Class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    information = models.CharField(max_length=255)

Class Price(models.Model):  
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_seen = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And I try to have for each product the max price and the associated date.
If I do

```
def get_max_price_for_product(request):
    max_price_list = (
        Price.objects.values("product__title", "product__name")
        .annotate(score=Max("price"))
        .order_by("-price")
    )

    context = {"max_price_list": max_price_list}
    return render(request, "prices/max_list.html", context)
```

I've the max price for each product but without the date. I read the Django doc but I didn't find (or I didn't understand what I read) how to do this.

Can somebody help me ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to work with a `QuerySet` with `Product` as the main model, so:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Product.objects.annotate(max_price=Max('price__price'))
```

that way you retrieve `Product` objects with an extra attribute `.max_price`, but it still functions like a `Product` object, so you can follow `ForeignKey`s, etc.

You can obtain the modification date by using a subquery:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max, OuterRef, Subquery


def get_max_price_for_product(request):
    Product.objects.annotate(
        max_price=Max('price__price'),
        max_price_date=Subquery(
            Price.objects.filter(product_id=OuterRef('pk'))
            .order_by(F('price').desc(nulls_last=True))
            .values('date_seen')[:1]
        ),
    )
    context = {'max_price_list': max_price_list}
    return render(request, 'prices/max_list.html', context)
```

This will retrieve the `date_seen` for the largest price.